# Radiated Emissions problem

Tags: emc, common-mode, hdmi, ferrite-bead, near-field

This is regarding some Radiated Emissions testing unintentional radiator.
We did a pre-scan of our product and we got the following EMI signature.

Critical frequency is at 314.986 MHz

Polarization is Horizontal

Peak detector is 53 dBμV/m

Quasi-Peak detector is 56.68 dBμV/m
[image]

I performed some near field probing with a spectrum analyzer and near field probes and I was able to detect that the radiation comes from our HDMI cable.
The cable connects to our unit and to a monitor. When performing the near field, I found that the pixel clock our our system generates a fundamental and there are harmonics. The peak observed in the lab that is causing us issues is a harmonic of that fundamental. [image]

We changed the slew rate and it improved the fundamental but the 3rd harmonic the 315MHz is not affected.
We also increased the value of the common-mode chokes on the data lines of the HDMI.
[image]

Here is a table with the comparison :
[image]

Now my question:

- How can we affect the amplitude of the fundamental (78.75MHz) with the changes we implemented but not lower the 3rd harmonic?
- Is it possible that the amplitude does not decrease in the near field, but will be lower in the far field if we are able to lower the fundamental?
- Are there other things we can do besides changing the common-mode chokes?

Comment: Are you testing with a shielded or unshielded hdmi cable?

Comment: shielded HDMI cable @VoltageSpike

Comment: Can you show photos of cable attachment, grounding to the case, and board shielding? Radiated emissions are often down to poor shield grounding allowing signals from inside to "leak" onto the outside of the shielding.

Comment: surprising that reduced slew rate did not reduce 3rd harmonics! Does the picture change when you attach a different monitor?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, we tested with a 4k monitor with the slowest slew rate and we still have a decent picture, when we change the resolution, the clock frequency changes, so try to stay consistent with the resolution, trying not to change too many things at the same time.

Comment: Fully get that! It's just that I wonder whether it might be the recovered pixel clock in the monitor that bleeds back into the cable… it's a long shot, but this is really surprising to me! (what I meant with "changed picture" is "changed relation of harmonic powers")

Comment: I sniffed the whole length of the cable near the monitor, near the unit and the noise is really near the unit. When we changed the monitor, the harmonic's power is about the same. I will do another test in the next few hours @MarcusMüller

Comment: ah that is a good test, though, stick with limiting variables and stay on one monitor

Comment: yes so the harmonic's power is the same pretty much even with a different monitor ... @MarcusMüller